# Unable to get grand total in Ajax calculation form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I created a form like this:

[image]

The problem is that I am unable to get the grand total of the sub total fields.

I tried to create grand total fields same as sub total but no luck. I wonder if I made a mistake not to create some variables globally? Is there is any simple solution to do that? You can find the whole code here: http://autopartsdiscountcoupons.com/table/Form.html

```js
$("#con_qty116").bind('keyup mouseup', function() {
  var rate = 40;
  var qty = $("#con_qty116").val();
  var val = qty * rate;

  $("#con_qty116_td").text(val);
  sub_total_of_weather_sheild();
});

$("#con_qty117").bind('keyup mouseup', function() {
  var rate = 160;
  var qty = $("#con_qty117").val();
  var val = qty * rate;

  $("#con_qty117_td").text(val);
  sub_total_of_decorative_surface();

});

function sub_total_of_weather_sheild() {
  var td116 = parseInt($("#con_qty116_td").text());
  var sub_tot = td116;
  $("#weather_sheild_qty_sub_total").text(sub_tot);
  gr_total(sub_tot);
}

function sub_total_of_decorative_surface() {
  var td117 = parseInt($("#con_qty117_td").text());
  var sub_tot = td117;
  $("#decorative_surface_qty_sub_total").text(sub_tot);
}
```

```html
  <td>116</td>
  <td>Provide and apply Weathershield (Reputable Brand) minimum...
  </td>
  <td>Sft</td>
  <td><input id="con_qty116" name="con_qty116" type="number" /></td>
  <td>40</td>
  <td id="con_qty116_td">0</td>
  <th colspan="4">Sub Total</th>
  <td id="weather_sheild_qty_sub_total" colspan="2">0</td>
  <td>117</td>
  <td>Color Crete min 4mm thickness including surface preparation applied on prepared surface using Applicant Machine/Gun
  </td>
  <td>Sft</td>
  <td><input id="con_qty117" name="con_qty117" type="number" /></td>
  <td>160</td>
  <td id="con_qty117_td">0</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th colspan="4">Sub Total</th>
  <td id="decorative_surface_qty_sub_total" colspan="2">0</td>
</tr>

<th colspan="4">Grand Total</th>
<th colspan="2" id="grand_total">0</th>
```

Comment: Your script is longer than your table, which means something is wrong. Try to restructure the code, so the calculation can be done easily. Use same classes for same type of fields and you can also use `data-attributes`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you do calculations via script is really dramatic. Writing a function for each row in table has no sense - because you ended with more than 100 of function definitions.

Therefor you have to restructure code and re-use same (one) function to calculate sum. Below you can see how it can be done, hope you get an idea:

```js
function calculateAll(e) {
    var grandTotal = 0;
    $('.sub_table').each(function(i) {
        var thisTable = $(this);
        var subTotal = 0;
        thisTable.find('tbody tr').each(function(j) {
            var thisRow = $(this);
            var amount = parseInt(thisRow.find('.multi1').val()) * thisRow.find('.multi2').val();
            subTotal += amount;
            thisRow.find('.amount').val(amount);
        });
        grandTotal += subTotal;
        thisTable.find('.subtotal').val(subTotal);
    });
    $('.grandtotal').val(grandTotal);
};
$('.sub_table input').on('input', calculateAll);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="sub_table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>S.No.</th>
            <th>EARTH WORK</th>
            <th>Unit </th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Rate</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Excavation for foundation...
            </td>
            <td>Cft</td>
            <td><input class="multi1" value="0" type="number" /></td>
            <td><input class="multi2" value="12" readonly /></td>
            <td><input class="amount" value="0" readonly /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>Backfilling / Earth Fill...
            </td>
            <td>Cft</td>
            <td><input class="multi1" value="0" type="number" /></td>
            <td><input class="multi2" value="120" readonly /></td>
            <td><input class="amount" value="0" readonly /></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="4">Sub Total</th>
            <td colspan="2"><input class="subtotal" value="0" readonly /></td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>

<table class="sub_table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>S.No.</th>
            <th>EARTH WORK</th>
            <th>Unit </th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Rate</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Excavation for foundation...
            </td>
            <td>Cft</td>
            <td><input class="multi1" value="0" type="number" /></td>
            <td><input class="multi2" value="25" readonly /></td>
            <td><input class="amount" value="0" readonly /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>Backfilling / Earth Fill...
            </td>
            <td>Cft</td>
            <td><input class="multi1" value="0" type="number" /></td>
            <td><input class="multi2" value="18" readonly /></td>
            <td><input class="amount" value="0" readonly /></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="4">Sub Total</th>
            <td colspan="2"><input class="subtotal" value="0" readonly /></td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
<p>
    Your Grand Total is <input class="grandtotal" value="0" readonly />
</p>
```

Also on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ebd6tahj/).

Answer (score 0):

On each function when you update sub total then you also get every sub total and sum all of these and put in sub total . Follow steps :-

1. Get the value of each sub total in grand_total() function

   ```
   function grand_total(){
     var grand_total = parseInt($("#ew_qty_sub_total").text());
     grand_total += parseInt($("#con_qty_sub_total").text());
     grand_total += parseInt($("#rein_qty_sub_total").text());
     .
     .       
     .   

    grand_total += parseInt($("#weather_sheild_qty_sub_total").text());
    grand_total += parseInt($("#decorative_surface_qty_sub_total").text());

    $("#grand_total").text(grand_total);

   }
   ```
2. call this function in your each keyup/mouseup function. like this:-

   ```
   $("#ew_qty1").bind('keyup mouseup',function ()
   {

     var rate = 12;
     // Take Quantity from user
     var qty = $("#ew_qty1").val();

     // Multiply Quantity By 10
     var val = qty*rate;

     // Set Text In TD
     $("#ew_qty1_td").text(val);
     sub_total_of_earth_Work();

     grand_total();   //call for total of sub total 


   });
   ```